# How can i open another jframe from another jframe function without waiting to complete the execution of function?

Tags: java, swing

I want to show a progress bar. I put the code to open the `JFrame` containing progress bar at the beginning of the function. But the progress bar opens only after the complete execution of the function

```
public void function(){
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ProgressSearch().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    instruction 1;
    instruction 2;
    instruction 3;
    instruction 4;
    instruction 5;
}
```

this code above only displays the progress bar after completing the function

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Also, try removing the invoke later and just have `new ProgressSearch().setVisible(true);` instead of `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...}`

Comment: I TRIED THAT ONLY FRAME IS VISIBLE. NO PROGRESS BAR

Comment: Okay please don't shout. It was only a suggestion. As I said post a MCVE or a SSSCE for better help

Comment: Yeah, that will not work. Just put the instructions in the `windowOpened` event of `ProgressSearch`

Comment: 1) As @Dan already suggested: post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). **Voting to close for lack of one.** 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding static "progress fields" to your class. Then just update those fields as your JFrame is created, and get their values on your code using Class.StaticField

e.g.,

```
public class MyClass {
    public static PROGRESS;
    public MyClass () {...}
    (...)
    PROGRESS = (...);
    (...)
    PROGRESS = (...);
    (...)
}
```

and get `MyClass.PROGRESS`

Also, don't forget to reset PROGRESS variable after the full completion so that every time you create another JFrame from the same class you get a clean progress from 0.

Regards,